# Select2 al enviar el formulario con error, deja de funcionar

Tags: symfony2, bootstrap-3, select2

Como parte de un menú contextual asociado a los nodos de un `JStree` muestro un formulario en un diálogo de Bootstrap 3, y dos de sus campos son `Select2`. sucede que al enviar el formulario con errores, deja de funcionar el Select2. Realmente no se dónde ubicar o el selector A emplear para que se mantenga el efecto del Select2 si hubiera error en el formulario.

```
$(document.body).find('#modalCrearEstructura').remove();
                                $(document.body).append("<div id='modalCrearEstructura' class='modal fade' tabindex='-1'  role='dialog'><div class='modal-dialog'><div class='modal-content'><div class='modal-header'><button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-label='Cerrar'><span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span></button><h5 class='modal-title' id='myModalLabel'><strong>Crear Estructura</strong></h5></div><div class='modal-body'><div id='contenedorForm' class='container-fluid'></div></div><div class='modal-footer'><button type='button' class='btn btn-default' data-dismiss='modal'>Cerrar</button><button id='btnSalvar' type='button' class='btn btn-primary'>Guardar</button></div></div></div></div>");
                                $("#contenedorForm").html(data);
                                $('#modalCrearEstructura').modal({
                                    keyboard: false,
                                    backdrop: 'static'
                                }).on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
                                    e.preventDefault();
                                    $(this).find('#colaborador_perfilColaborador, #colaborador_provinciaCuba').select2({
                                        dropdownParent: $('#modalCrearEstructura')
                                    });
                                    $('#contenedorForm form').on('submit', function (e) {
                                        e.preventDefault();
                                        return false;
                                    });
                                    var dialogo = $(this);
                                    $("#btnSalvar").on('click', function (e) {
                                        e.preventDefault();
                                        var btn = $(this);
                                        if (!btn.hasClass('disabled')) {
                                            $.ajax({
                                                dataType: 'json',
                                                type: 'POST',
                                                url: $("#modalCrearEstructura").find("form").attr('action'),
                                                data: $("#modalCrearEstructura").find("form").serialize(),
                                                beforeSend: function () {
                                                    btn.toggleClass('disabled');
                                                    $('#indicador').addClass('cargando-satisfactorio').slideDown('fast');
                                                }
                                            }).done(function (data) {
                                                if (inst.is_open(node)) {
                                                    inst.create_node(node, data, 'last');
                                                } else {
                                                    inst.refresh_node(node);
                                                    inst.open_node(node);
                                                }
                                                cargarVistaCentral(node);
                                                $('#modalCrearEstructura').modal('hide');
                                            }).fail(function (jqXHR) {
                                                if (jqXHR.status === 401) {
                                                    window.location = _HOMEPAGE;
                                                } else if (jqXHR.status === 406) {
                                                    $(dialogo).find('#contenedorForm').html(jqXHR.responseText);
                                                } else {
                                                    $('#indicador').removeClass('cargando-satisfactorio').addClass('cargando-error').html(jqXHR.responseText);
                                                }
                                            }).always(function () {
                                                btn.toggleClass('disabled');
                                                if (!$('#indicador').hasClass("cargando-satisfactorio")) {
                                                    setTimeout(function () {
                                                        $('#indicador').fadeOut('fast', function () {
                                                            $(this).removeClass('cargando-error').html("<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-time'></span> Cargando...");
                                                        });
                                                    }, 3000);
                                                } else {
                                                    $('#indicador').fadeOut('fast', function () {
                                                        $(this).removeClass('cargando-satisfactorio').html("<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-time'></span> Cargando...");
                                                    });
                                                }
                                            });
                                        } else {
                                            return false;
                                        }
                                    });

                                }).on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
                                    e.preventDefault();
                                    $('#modalCrearEstructura').remove();
                                });
```

Comment: Podrias adjuntar que error te da ?

Comment: no da error, simplemente se pierde el efecto Select2 de los campos.

Answer (score 0):

la solución estuvo basada en quitar el código que convierte los select en Select2 del código anterior. Quedando de la siguiente manera:

```
$(document.body).find('#modalCrearEstructura').remove();
                                $(document.body).append("<div id='modalCrearEstructura' class='modal fade' tabindex='-1'  role='dialog'><div class='modal-dialog'><div class='modal-content'><div class='modal-header'><button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-label='Cerrar'><span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span></button><h5 class='modal-title' id='myModalLabel'><strong>Crear Estructura</strong></h5></div><div class='modal-body'><div id='contenedorForm' class='container-fluid'></div></div><div class='modal-footer'><button type='button' class='btn btn-default' data-dismiss='modal'>Cerrar</button><button id='btnSalvar' type='button' class='btn btn-primary'>Guardar</button></div></div></div></div>");
                                $("#contenedorForm").html(data);
                                $('#modalCrearEstructura').modal({
                                    keyboard: false,
                                    backdrop: 'static'
                                }).on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
                                    e.preventDefault();                                        
                                    $('#contenedorForm form').on('submit', function (e) {
                                        e.preventDefault();
                                        return false;
                                    });
                                    var dialogo = $(this);
                                    $("#btnSalvar").on('click', function (e) {
                                        e.preventDefault();
                                        var btn = $(this);
                                        if (!btn.hasClass('disabled')) {
                                            $.ajax({
                                                dataType: 'json',
                                                type: 'POST',
                                                url: $("#modalCrearEstructura").find("form").attr('action'),
                                                data: $("#modalCrearEstructura").find("form").serialize(),
                                                beforeSend: function () {
                                                    btn.toggleClass('disabled');
                                                    $('#indicador').addClass('cargando-satisfactorio').slideDown('fast');
                                                }
                                            }).done(function (data) {
                                                if (inst.is_open(node)) {
                                                    inst.create_node(node, data, 'last');
                                                } else {
                                                    inst.refresh_node(node);
                                                    inst.open_node(node);
                                                }
                                                cargarVistaCentral(node);
                                                $('#modalCrearEstructura').modal('hide');
                                            }).fail(function (jqXHR) {
                                                if (jqXHR.status === 401) {
                                                    window.location = _HOMEPAGE;
                                                } else if (jqXHR.status === 406) {
                                                    $(dialogo).find('#contenedorForm').html(jqXHR.responseText);
                                                } else {
                                                    $('#indicador').removeClass('cargando-satisfactorio').addClass('cargando-error').html(jqXHR.responseText);
                                                }
                                            }).always(function () {
                                                btn.toggleClass('disabled');
                                                if (!$('#indicador').hasClass("cargando-satisfactorio")) {
                                                    setTimeout(function () {
                                                        $('#indicador').fadeOut('fast', function () {
                                                            $(this).removeClass('cargando-error').html("<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-time'></span> Cargando...");
                                                        });
                                                    }, 3000);
                                                } else {
                                                    $('#indicador').fadeOut('fast', function () {
                                                        $(this).removeClass('cargando-satisfactorio').html("<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-time'></span> Cargando...");
                                                    });
                                                }
                                            });
                                        } else {
                                            return false;
                                        }
                                    });

                                }).on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
                                    e.preventDefault();
                                    $('#modalCrearEstructura').remove();
                                });
```

y en el archivo `JS` de la aplicación declarado el mismo:

```
$("#modalCrearEstructura").find('#colaborador_perfilColaborador, #colaborador_provinciaCuba').select2({
            dropdownParent: $('#modalCrearEstructura')
        });
```